# How to create a pivot table in R with multiple (3+) variables

Tags: r, reshape

I am having problems in create a pivot table with a data frame like this:

```
c1   c2          c3         c4
E   5.76         201    A la vista
E   47530.71     201    A la vista
E   82.85        201    A la vista
L   11376.55     201    A la vista
E   6683.37      203    A la vista
E   66726.52     203    A la vista
E   2.39         203    A la vista
E   79066.07     202    Montoxv_a60d
E   14715.71     202    Montoxv_a60d
E   22661.78     202    Montoxv_a60d
L   81146.25     124    Montoxv_a90d
L   471730.2     124    Montoxv_a186d
E   667812.84    124    Montoxv_a186d
```

My problem is that I don't know how to create in R a pivot table or summary table with four variables, considering for the final table in the rows, the levels of `c1` and  `c3` and as columns the levels of `c4`. The values of `c2` variable must be aggregated by sum for each level considered in rows. I would like to get something like this:

```
       A la vista   Montoxv_a60d   Montoxv_a186d  Montoxv_a90d
E 201    47619.32       0               0               0  
E 203    73412.28       0               0               0 
E 202    0           116443.56          0               0      
E 124    0              0            667812.84          0 
L 201    11376.55       0               0               0
L 124    0              0            471730.2         81146.25
```

Comment: May be you can try `reshape`

Comment: The base solution is either table or ftable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this with dcast from the `reshape2` package:

```
dcast(mydata, c1 + c3 ~ c4, value.var="c2", fun.aggregate=sum)
```

For example:

```
library(reshape2)
# reproducible version of your data
mydata = read.csv(text="c1,c2,c3,c4
    E,5.76,201,A la vista
    E,47530.71,201,A la vista
    E,82.85,201,A la vista
    L,11376.55,201,A la vista
    E,6683.37,203,A la vista
    E,66726.52,203,A la vista
    E,2.39,203,A la vista
    E,79066.07,202,Montoxv_a60d
    E,14715.71,202,Montoxv_a60d
    E,22661.78,202,Montoxv_a60d
    L,81146.25,124,Montoxv_a90d
    L,471730.2,124,Montoxv_a186d
    E,667812.84,124,Montoxv_a186d", header=TRUE)
result = dcast(mydata, c1 + c3 ~ c4, value.var="c2", fun.aggregate=sum)
```

produces:

```
  c1  c3 A la vista Montoxv_a186d Montoxv_a60d Montoxv_a90d
1  E 124       0.00      667812.8          0.0         0.00
2  E 201   47619.32           0.0          0.0         0.00
3  E 202       0.00           0.0     116443.6         0.00
4  E 203   73412.28           0.0          0.0         0.00
5  L 124       0.00      471730.2          0.0     81146.25
6  L 201   11376.55           0.0          0.0         0.00
```

Comment: You  can also skip `paste` and use `c1 + c3 ~ c4` to keep them in separate columns with the same aggregated results.

Comment: @Justin: Upon reflection I do like that result better, though I'm not certain which the OP was looking for

Comment: Both are useful and valid.  The base `R` reshape, whose syntax is a perpetual mystery to me, can accomplish something similar to the paste method I think...

Answer (score 5):

The request: "The values of c2 variable must be aggregated by sum for each level" can be decomposed into an aggregation step that use `tapply` to create a 3-dimensional table object which can then be presented as flattened (with `ftable`) with 2 dimensions on the rows and one dimension for columns:

```
ftable(with(mydata, tapply(c2, list(c1,c3,c4), sum) ) )

           A la vista Montoxv_a186d Montoxv_a60d Montoxv_a90d
                                                             
    E 124          NA     667812.84           NA           NA
      201    47619.32            NA           NA           NA
      202          NA            NA    116443.56           NA
      203    73412.28            NA           NA           NA
    L 124          NA     471730.20           NA     81146.25
      201    11376.55            NA           NA           NA
      202          NA            NA           NA           NA
      203          NA            NA           NA           NA
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few more options, two in base R and one using the more recent "dplyr" and "tidyr" packages.

Base R's `reshape` can't handle aggregation, so you need to resort to other functions (for example, `aggregate`) before you can do the reshaping.

```
reshape(
  aggregate(c2 ~ c1 + c3 + c4, mydata, sum), 
  direction = "wide", idvar = c("c1", "c3"), timevar = "c4")
#      c1  c3 c2.A la vista c2.Montoxv_a186d c2.Montoxv_a60d c2.Montoxv_a90d
# 1     E 201      47619.32               NA              NA              NA
# 2     L 201      11376.55               NA              NA              NA
# 3     E 203      73412.28               NA              NA              NA
# 4     E 124            NA         667812.8              NA              NA
# 5     L 124            NA         471730.2              NA        81146.25
# 6     E 202            NA               NA        116443.6              NA
```

If your aggregation only involves sum, you can also use `xtabs` to do the aggregation. Since you have multiple values on the RHS of the formula, you'll end up with a multi-dimensional `array`, but that can easily be coerced into a rectangular form by using `ftable` (as was done by @BondedDust in his answer). Note that the output using `ftable` is a little different from others in that it returns all combinations of grouping variables by default, even where there would otherwise be fully empty rows.

```
ftable(xtabs(c2 ~ c1 + c3 + c4, mydata))
#           c4 A la vista Montoxv_a186d Montoxv_a60d Montoxv_a90d
# c1    c3                                                       
#     E 124          0.00     667812.84         0.00         0.00
#       201      47619.32          0.00         0.00         0.00
#       202          0.00          0.00    116443.56         0.00
#       203      73412.28          0.00         0.00         0.00
#     L 124          0.00     471730.20         0.00     81146.25
#       201      11376.55          0.00         0.00         0.00
#       202          0.00          0.00         0.00         0.00
#       203          0.00          0.00         0.00         0.00
```

---

Finally, you can also use the functions in "tidyr" and "dplyr" which offer similar functionality to the tools in "reshape" and "reshape2", but with a slightly different "grammar".

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%                     ## The source dataset
  group_by(c1, c3, c4) %>%     ## Grouping variables
  summarise(c2 = sum(c2)) %>%  ## aggregation of the c2 column
  ungroup() %>%                ## spread doesn't seem to like groups
  spread(c4, c2)               ## spread makes the data wide
# Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
# 
#      c1  c3 A la vista Montoxv_a186d Montoxv_a60d Montoxv_a90d
# 1     E 124         NA      667812.8           NA           NA
# 2     E 201   47619.32            NA           NA           NA
# 3     E 202         NA            NA     116443.6           NA
# 4     E 203   73412.28            NA           NA           NA
# 5     L 124         NA      471730.2           NA     81146.25
# 6     L 201   11376.55            NA           NA           NA
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be easily produced by the `pivottabler` package - using either the one-line quick-pivot function or the more verbose syntax:

```
df <- read.csv(text="c1,c2,c3,c4
    E,5.76,201,A la vista
    E,47530.71,201,A la vista
    E,82.85,201,A la vista
    L,11376.55,201,A la vista
    E,6683.37,203,A la vista
    E,66726.52,203,A la vista
    E,2.39,203,A la vista
    E,79066.07,202,Montoxv_a60d
    E,14715.71,202,Montoxv_a60d
    E,22661.78,202,Montoxv_a60d
    L,81146.25,124,Montoxv_a90d
    L,471730.2,124,Montoxv_a186d
    E,667812.84,124,Montoxv_a186d", header=TRUE)

# quick pivot syntax
library(pivottabler)
qhpvt(df, c("c1","c3"), "c4", "sum(c2)", totals="NONE")

# verbose syntax
library(pivottabler)
pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(df) 
pt$addColumnDataGroups("c4", addTotal=FALSE)
pt$addRowDataGroups("c1", addTotal=FALSE)
pt$addRowDataGroups("c3", addTotal=FALSE)
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="calc1", summariseExpression="sum(c2)")
pt$renderPivot()
```

Output:

[image: output]

More info about the `pivottabler` package at:
http://pivottabler.org.uk/articles/v01-introduction.html

NB:  I am the package author.

Answer (score 1):

With rpivotTable, you can pivot like in Excel.

```
install.packages("rpivotTable")
library(rpivotTable) 
data(mtcars)
rpivotTable(mtcars)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `pivot_wider` function in `tidyr` this can be done with ease

```
library(tidyr)
tidyr::pivot_wider(data = df, id_cols = c(c1, c3), names_from = c4, values_from = c2, values_fn = sum)

# A tibble: 6 x 6
  c1         c3 `A la vista` Montoxv_a60d Montoxv_a90d Montoxv_a186d
  <chr>   <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
1 "    E"   201       47619.          NA           NA            NA 
2 "    L"   201       11377.          NA           NA            NA 
3 "    E"   203       73412.          NA           NA            NA 
4 "    E"   202          NA       116444.          NA            NA 
5 "    L"   124          NA           NA        81146.       471730.
6 "    E"   124          NA           NA           NA        667813.
```

Answer (score 0):

The **data.table** package has, similar to the **reshape2** package the functions `dcast()` and `melt()` for this kind of operations. Hence you can do:

```r
require(data.table)

setDT(mydata)
dcast(mydata, c1 + c3 ~ c4,
      value.var = "c2", fun.aggregate = sum)
```

This will also be the fastest solution.

---

Data from @david-robinson.

```r
mydata = read.csv(text = "c1,c2,c3,c4
    E,5.76,201,A la vista
    E,47530.71,201,A la vista
    E,82.85,201,A la vista
    L,11376.55,201,A la vista
    E,6683.37,203,A la vista
    E,66726.52,203,A la vista
    E,2.39,203,A la vista
    E,79066.07,202,Montoxv_a60d
    E,14715.71,202,Montoxv_a60d
    E,22661.78,202,Montoxv_a60d
    L,81146.25,124,Montoxv_a90d
    L,471730.2,124,Montoxv_a186d
    E,667812.84,124,Montoxv_a186d", header = TRUE)
```