# R pivot table with multiple column levels

Tags: r, pivot-table

I would be grateful if anyone could tell me how to create pivot table in R like python pandas with selected aggregation function and more then one level in column.

I would like to receive in R something like this in python:

`Iris.pivot_table(index='Sepal.Length',columns=['Sepal.Width','Species'],values='Petal.Length',aggfunc=sum)`

I know there is pivotabler package, but default rendering to html method is to slow for a bit larger tables.

I also have found ftable function from stats package but its only for contingency tables, in which I can`t specify my own aggregation function.

Thank you.

Comment: Some possible solutions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622854/how-to-create-a-pivot-table-in-r-with-more-than-3-variables).

Comment: For those of us who don't use python and don't know what a pivot table is, it might be helpful to put an example of the output you want to get.